# Random line break is added to H2 on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile

I am working on a UI that includes an infobar (100% width on mobile devices), which includes a title and and icon to send a message. Both elements are floating but when viewing the site on a mobile devices (Android/iPhone) it breaks up the headline over two lines. There is enough space though to keep it on a single line but it still does it.

I don't have the same problem on my Mac when resizing the window to 320px.

Any idea?

```
.page_layout .page-head .info-bar {
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
}

.page_layout .page-head .info-bar h2 {
    float: left;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #333;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 2px 0 0 5px;
}

.page_layout .page-head .info-bar .connect-icon {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    float: right;
    background-color: #A2AB58;
    margin-right: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to add a 1px black border to the h2 to see if theres really enough space or if some margin/padding is stealing you some px.

Other thing would be to set the following css attribute and then try again on the mobile device:

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

Comment: Hi Marc, there was definitely enough space. But "white-space:nowrap;" did the trick! Thanks so much!!